# pt-BR no datePicker não funciona no AdminLTE 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, adminlte

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um painel e preciso do datepicker em portugues, 
já tentei modificar do próprio arquivo js mas as datas desapareciam.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        language:'pt-BR',
        format: {
            /*
             * Say our UI should display a week ahead,
             * but textbox should store the actual date.
             * This is useful if we need UI to select local dates,
             * but store in UTC
             */
            toDisplay: function (date, format, language) {
                var language ='pt-BR';
                var data = new Date(date);
                var dia = date.getDate()+1;
                console.log(dia);
                if (dia.toString().length == 1)
                  dia = "0"+dia;
                var mes = data.getMonth()+1;
                if (mes.toString().length == 1)
                  mes = "0"+mes;
                var ano = data.getFullYear();
                //console.log(moment().format('mm'));
                console.log(language);  
                return dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano;

            },
            toValue: function (date, format, language) {
                var d = new Date(date);
                d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
                // console.log(new Date(d));
                return new Date(d);
            }
        }




    });
  });
```

Comment: Para que esse `format`? Tente assim: `$('#datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        startView: 2,
        language: "pt-BR"      
    });`

Comment: Ele pegou o valor do dia anterior.

Comment: Ficou em português?

Comment: Agora tive a opção de escolha do ano e mês mas não traduziu. @JorgeMatheus

Comment: Encontrei o erro @JorgeMatheus, a versão minificada estava definida como 'en'  então priorizou esta config linkei ai consegui definir na chamada do script.

Comment: show, ainda bem que resolveu!